# Function overloading problems C++

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

I'm running an option pricing model that yields four values for four different options.

```
class EuroOption
{
private:
    double S;    //underlying stock price
    double X;    //strike price
    double sigma;    //volatility
    double T;    //time to expiration
    double r;    //risk-free rate
    double b;    //cost of carry
public:
    EuroOption();    //default constructor
    ~EuroOption();    //destructor
    EuroOption(const EuroOption& eo);    //copy constructor
    EuroOption& operator = (const EuroOption& source);    //assignment operator
    EuroOption(vector<double> Batch1);
    EuroOption(vector<double> Batch2);  //this is the error: redeclaration
    //EuroOption(vector<double> const Batch3);
    //EuroOption(vector<double> const Batch4);
```

Here is the source material from .cpp:

```
EuroOption::EuroOption(vector<double> Batch1) : S(60), X(65), sigma(0.30), r(0.08), T(0.25), b(r)
{
}

EuroOption::EuroOption(vector<double> Batch2) : S(100), X(100), sigma(0.20), r(0), T(1), b(r)
{
}
```

The errors I'm getting are "constructor cannot be redeclared". But my functions have different arguments(Batch1/Batch2) so I don't understand why it's not overloading. The output for Batch2 is also the same as Batch 1 (this is not correct). I'd be grateful for the guidance you may have.

Comment: The constructors have exactly the same *parameter type*. The name of the parameters is irrelevant. How could you resolve between those two methods at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the intent of what you want to do is to tag dispatch the constructor, or something similar, so that EuroOption is constructed with different hard-coded defaults.

```
struct Batch1{};
struct Batch2{};

class EuroOption
{
private:
    double S;    //underlying stock price
    double X;    //strike price
    double sigma;    //volatility
    double T;    //time to expiration
    double r;    //risk-free rate
    double b;    //cost of carry
public:
    EuroOption();    //default constructor
    ~EuroOption();    //destructor
    EuroOption(const EuroOption& eo);    //copy constructor
    EuroOption& operator = (const EuroOption& source);    //assignment operator
    EuroOption(Batch1);
    EuroOption(Batch2);
```

.cpp file:

```
EuroOption::EuroOption(Batch1) : S(60), X(65), sigma(0.30), r(0.08), T(0.25), b(r)
{
}

EuroOption::EuroOption(Batch2) : S(100), X(100), sigma(0.20), r(0), T(1), b(r)
{
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code it could be constructed as:

```
EuroOption option1{Batch1{}};
EuroOption option2{Batch2{}};
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your edits. But for "EuroOption option1{Batch1{}};" I am getting an error "expected '}' to match this '{'. Am I missing something?

Comment: What compiler are you using? That syntax will require a reasonably modern one.

Comment: I think you will need to have the command line option -std=c++11.
Edit: cool

Answer (score 5):

The overloading is based on the parameter types not parameter names.

```
EuroOption::EuroOption(vector<double> Batch1)
```

Here `vector<double>` is the parameter type and `Batch1` is the parameter name.
If you want overloading functions, you should declare functions with different parameter types or different number of parameters.

For eg, these are overloaded functions,

```
EuroOption::EuroOption(vector<double> Batch1)
EuroOption::EuroOption(vector<int> Batch1)
EuroOption::EuroOption(string Batch1)
```

Answer (score 1):

These constructors are same:

```
EuroOption(vector<double> Batch1);
EuroOption(vector<double> Batch2);
```

These declarations are equivalent to:

```
EuroOption(vector<double>);
EuroOption(vector<double>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the function signature is the same. This is determined by the return type, name and number and type of the arguments.

Although the parameter name is different, the functions have exactly the same signature. In your example, when you call the constructor how do you decide which constructor gets called? The only difference is the parameter name but that is not accessible to the caller.

For future reference check: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/

Comment: Note that for a non-template function, the return type does not form part of the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Method Overloading means same method different signatures
 EuroOption(vector Batch1);
 EuroOption(vector Batch2);
same method has declared two times in the same class cause an error method redeclaration